# Is there a way to restore the original sorting in a Numbers table?

Tags: numbers

I have just started using Numbers and I started messing around with the organization options. Filters and categories work great, however, sorting has a weird behaviour.

If I sort the rows by a given column and then remove that sorting rule, the original row order is not restored. I couldn't find any simple way to restore it :/

How can it be done?

Comment: Is this on macOS or iOS?

Comment: @Nathan it is macOS

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is 'undo' i.e. ⌘+Z until you reach the desired (previous) state. 'Undo' applies to anything what is 'done' in a file, so pending on how many changes are made it may be lot of undoing.

Answer (score 0):

I would, and almost always do, two things:

1. add a column numbering the items so that the original order can be restored easily - often necessary when the original data is not already in a specific order such as alphabetic etc
2. keep a copy of the original and I always work on a duplicate so when things go wrong I can return to the original. I also save prior to making changes so that I can revert to the previous state.

These have saved me often and apply to any spreadsheet program and other data handling programs....

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait a bit more for an answer on how to restore the original ordering but if there is no way I'll do as you said and create a new column numbering the items.

Answer (score 0):

The original data was sorted by one of the columns and you need to know which. If you remember the 1st row of data you can maybe figure out which column it was sorted on. If you haven't made many changes there is an option under the File menu called "Revert To" which reverts the file back to how you opened it. This may be your best bet. You can revert and then figure out which column it was sorted on.